# How can I enable one-finger scrolling in Unity?

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch, interface, scrolling

I would like to activate to scroll with **one** finger inside the Unity environment(nautilus, Dash, Firefox). Because Unity claims to be touch screen friendly but scrolling with two fingers is annoying and doesn't work so well.

Comment: I don't know how to enable it, but I wish I knew how to *dissable* it ):

Answer (score 0):

**with a touchpad:** You use either the regular scrollbar or the *overlay scrollbar* on the right edge of your application window.

You can activate the overlay scrollbar by simply hovering near the right edge until you see it popup, and then tap and drag it up or down.

[image]

Comment: I know about the overlay scrollbars (it's nice by the way) But it's not possible for me to activate them with the finger. When using the stylus, no problem, because it behaves like a mouse cursor if you only hover over the screen without touching it.

Answer (score 0):

Workin flawlessy here out of the box. Just tap and drag your finger on Nautilus e.g. just like a smartphone. (Doesn't work with firefox)

Comment: Does not work for me. Is it working for you in Unity Dash? And how do you select multiple items in nautilus, because then I guess there is no way to pull a select-frame?

Comment: Please try and give answers to questions, not your experience/results. :)